# Access other xaml controls data in another control's event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

I have below listbox to which i am binding data from a class(SavedDataClass) defined.When user clicks on link "Update" i want to access the entire data of other members of that particular instance of SavedDataClass .Is that possible to access the data like that ? I mean how to access other xxaml controls data in a  listbox item instance when one of its member is invoked ..

```
        <ListBox x:Name="lstAreaDetails"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0"  >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel >

                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Name="MyDateTime" Text="{Binding MyDateTime}"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>                                        
                                    <StackPanel >                                           
                                        <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding SavedName}" Name="lnkSAvedName"  Click="HyperlinkButton_Click_1"   />
                                        <HyperlinkButton  Content="{Binding Update}" Name="lnkUpdate" Click="lnkUpdate_click"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock   Text="{Binding ResAddress}" Name="txtResAddress" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock >OtherDetails:</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Area}" Name="txtArea" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

 public class SavedDataClass
{
    public string MyDateTime { get; set; }
    public string SavedName { get; set; }
    public string Update{ get; set; }
    public string ResAddress { get; set; }
    public string Area{ get; set; }
    public string OptionalAddressLine1{ get; set; }
    public string OptionalAddressLine2{ get; set; }
}
```

update link click will have below event handler:

```
 private void lnkUpdate_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      //here I want to access other controls data e.g. MyDateTime,SavedName,ResAddress,Area,OptionalAddressLine1,OptionalAddresLine2
    }
```

Comment: You data object (SaveDataClass) should be in the DataContext property of the clicked Button

Comment: I have the property "public string Update{ get; set; }" binding to the update button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these situations, the `Tag` property of `FrameworkElement` is used to transport the underlying data object that resides within the `DataContext` you're binding to. Your code would look somewhat like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstAreaDetails" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Name="MyDateTime" Text="{Binding MyDateTime}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>                                        
                <StackPanel >                                           
                    <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding SavedName}" Name="lnkSAvedName"  Click="HyperlinkButton_Click_1"   />
                    <HyperlinkButton  Tag="{Binding}" Content="{Binding Update}" Name="lnkUpdate" Click="lnkUpdate_click"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock   Text="{Binding ResAddress}" Name="txtResAddress" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock >OtherDetails:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Area}" Name="txtArea" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Notice that on the second hyperlink button, I added the `Tag` attribute. Your code-behind would look somewhat like this:

```
private void lnkUpdate_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hyperlinkButton = sender as HyperlinkButton;
    if (hyperlinkButton == null)
        return;

    var savedDataClass = hyperlinkButton.Tag as SavedDataClass;
    // Do whatever you want with the saved data class instance here...
}
```

Hope this helps.